# How to read a file into multiple lists

Tags: python, file-io

Im working on a project where I need to read lines from a text file (named marks.txt) and from that put the values into lists. The file is organized so its just a matter of reading each line and adding it to each of the 5 lists in order, then repeating until the end of the file. I looked around, but was unable to find what Ineeded despite having a couple that seemed promising. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/python-read-file-line-by-line-into-array) had the right idea, but only applies to a single list, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24541562/read-multiple-data-file-into-multiple-arrays-python) seemed like it would be the answer, but its way more advanced than what I can use or understand. Filnally, I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250133/python-reading-from-file-into-multiple-lists), which is really close, and I tried doing something along the lines of answer 3 (miost similar to what I learned a couple years ago, but it does work for me. If anyone has any ideas on how i could adapt dome of those examples to my work that wuld be excellent. For this project, it doesnt have to be efficient, just working and simple in terms of elements used. Thi is what i have right now:

```
studentName= mark1=mark2= mark3=mark4 = []
dataFile=open(dataFileRaw, "r")
for line in dataFile:
    studentName.append(line) #line 1 goes to array one, line 6 goes to array 1, second value, etc
    mark1.append(line) #line 2 goes to array two
    mark2.append(line) #line 3 goes to array three
    mark3.append(line) #line 4 goes to array four
    mark4.append(line) #line 5 goes to array five
dataFile.close()
```

Comment: For clarity, my comments are how I'd like it to work, not how its working currently

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: it prodeces 5 lists, each of which contain the entire file 5 times, not 1/5th of the file

Comment: I guess [How to clone or copy a list in Python?][1] fits your question perfectly.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python

Comment: Darn, had to hand in my program missing a section of code on account of my bad time management, Thank you to everyone who gave a thorough answer. I wish I would have had the time to implement them. Ill sort through them tomorrow and choose the best.

Answer (score 3):

`studentName= mark1=mark2= mark3=mark4 = []` won't do what you want. It creates a single list and binds it to multiple names. So if you modify studentName the modifications will replicate to mark1, mark2 etc. See [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/python-list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

But here's some code that uses a list of lists which will gather your data properly. It uses `.strip()` to strip leading & trailing white space (including newlines) from each line of data. It also uses the `with` keyword so you don't need to explicitly close the file.

```
marks = [[] for _ in range(5)]

with open(dataFileRaw, "r") as dataFile:
    for i, line in enumerate(dataFile):
        marks[i % 5].append(line.strip())
```

---

`enumerate()` is a built-in function that takes an iterable object as its first argument and an optional start number as its second argument. It returns a new iterable object that yields pairs of values (in the form of tuples), with the first value in the pair being a count, and the second value being the next element from the original iterable object.

From `help(enumerate)`

> enumerate(iterable[, start]) -> iterator for index, value of iterable
>
> Return an enumerate object.  iterable must be another object that
>   supports iteration.  The enumerate object yields pairs containing a
>   count (from start, which defaults to zero) and a value yielded by the
>   iterable argument. enumerate is useful for obtaining an indexed list:
>
> ```
> (0, seq[0]), (1, seq[1]), (2, seq[2]), ...
> ```

It may help to see some examples:

```
for i,c in enumerate('qwerty'):    
    print i, c
```

**output**

```
0 q
1 w
2 e
3 r
4 t
5 y
```

We can also supply a `start` argument to `enumerate()`, eg

```
seq = ['one', 'two', 'three']
for i, c in enumerate(seq, 1):
    print i, c
```

**output**

```
1 one
2 two
3 three
```

---

The `%` operator is the modulo operator. `a % b` yields the remainder when we divide the integer `a` by the integer `b`. Eg,

```
for i in range(12):
    print i % 4
```

**output**

```
0
1
2
3
0
1
2
3
0
1
2
3
```

Putting `%` together with `enumerate()` lets us do this sort of thing:

```
for i, c in enumerate('_abcdefghij'):
    print i%5, c
```

**output**

```
0 _
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
0 e
1 f
2 g
3 h
4 i
0 j
```

So do you now understand what

```
for i, line in enumerate(dataFile):
    marks[i % 5].append(line.strip())
```

does?

Comment: would you mind explining breifly what the i%5 does in this case and what enumerate(datafile) does?

Comment: @qwerty22: Yeah, ok. See the new additions to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have here is that you haven't actually read the data from the dataFileRaw, you have simply instantiated the file using open(). You have to make sure you go about reading all of the data from the file via something along the lines of:

```
dataFromFile = dataFile.read()
```

This will pull all of the data as a string into the dataFile variable. The nice part about this is that afterwards, you can simply split this dataFile up into a list by splitting at the newline escape character \n (which is automatically added when you hit Enter in a text editor).

```
dataFromFile = dataFromFile.split("\n")[:-1]
```

The reason I added in the [:-1] at the end is because if you end each line in the text file with \n (it automatically is in the file if you used enter) it will cause the last element in the list to be empty, and you don't want to deal with this data, thus the [:-1] indicates that we are only interested in the range of data from index 0 inclusive, to the last element exclusive. Simply put, we drop the last list element.

And from there you simply switch the for loop to iterate through dataFromFile rather than dataFile.

Comment: right, so I actually had the file opening part, but forgot that when I pasted the code in

Comment: Ah, no. You can iterate over an open file line by line using something like `for line in filehandle:`; each `line` will retain the end of line terminator. Also, it's often preferable to process text files line by line (when practical) rather than reading the whole file into memory and then splitting it into lines. That way you can process files that are too huge to fit into memory.

Comment: Wow. I've been doing the above method for 2 years now, did not know about what you just mentioned. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this make a tuple of lines from your file, then make a lists of strings from tuple as you like:

```
lines = tuple(open("marks.txt", 'r'))
list1, list2, list3, list4, list5 = [], [], [], [], []
i, linesCount = 0, len(lines)

while (i < linesCount):
    list1.append(lines[i].rstrip())
    i += 1
    if (i < linesCount):
        list2.append(lines[i].rstrip())
        i += 1
    if (i < linesCount):
        list3.append(lines[i].rstrip())
        i += 1
    if (i < linesCount):
        list4.append(lines[i].rstrip())
        i += 1
    if (i < linesCount):
        list5.append(lines[i].rstrip())
        i += 1

print list1, list2, list3, list4, list5
```

Answer (score 0):

### The answer

```
s, g1, g2, g3, g4 = [[line.strip() for line in group_of_lines] for group_of_lines in zip(*zip(*[open('marks.txt')]*5))]
```

### How I derived the answer

From the prompt of the `ipython` shell:

```
In [38]: cat marks.txt
s1
g11
g12
g13
g14
s2
g21
g22
g23
g24
s3
g31
g32
g33
g34

In [39]: zip(*[open('marks.txt')]*5)
Out[39]: 
[('s1\n', 'g11\n', 'g12\n', 'g13\n', 'g14\n'),
 ('s2\n', 'g21\n', 'g22\n', 'g23\n', 'g24\n'),
 ('s3\n', 'g31\n', 'g32\n', 'g33\n', 'g34\n')]

In [40]: zip(*zip(*[open('marks.txt')]*5))
Out[40]: 
[('s1\n', 's2\n', 's3\n'),
 ('g11\n', 'g21\n', 'g31\n'),
 ('g12\n', 'g22\n', 'g32\n'),
 ('g13\n', 'g23\n', 'g33\n'),
 ('g14\n', 'g24\n', 'g34\n')]

In [41]: [[line.strip() for line in group_of_lines] for group_of_lines in zip(*zip(*[open('marks.txt')]*5))]
Out[41]: 
[['s1', 's2', 's3'],
 ['g11', 'g21', 'g31'],
 ['g12', 'g22', 'g32'],
 ['g13', 'g23', 'g33'],
 ['g14', 'g24', 'g34']]

In [42]: s, g1, g2, g3, g4 = [[line.strip() for line in group_of_lines] for group_of_lines in zip(*zip(*[open('marks.txt')]*5))]

In [43]: print '\n'.join(map(str,(s,g1,g2,g3,g4)))
['s1', 's2', 's3']
['g11', 'g21', 'g31']
['g12', 'g22', 'g32']
['g13', 'g23', 'g33']
['g14', 'g24', 'g34']

In [44]:
```

### A line by line commentary on *"How I derived the answer"*

#### [38]

My personal version of the `marks.txt` data file

#### [39]

The crux of the procedure, the
[grouper](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)
procedure shamelessly adapted from the `itertools` module [fine
docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).

A file object can be simply understood as an iterator that returns the
file content line by line, so we start with a list containing 5
(identical) copies of a file iterator that returns the content of our
data file, and pass *the elements* of this list (by using the `*` star
operator) to the `zip` builtin function, that returns a list of tuples
with an element from each one of its arguments, e.g.:

```
In [44]: zip(*[[1,2,3],[10,20,30]])
Out[44]: [(1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30)]
```

Because `zip` is passsed five identical copies of the same file
iterator, it builds a list of tuples containing the first five lines,
the second five lines, ..., of our file.

#### [40]

But we want it the other way around! Or, in other words, we want to
*transpose* our list of tuples.

Transposition of a sequence of sequences is usually obtained with an
idiom that's very similar to what we've just seen...

```
In [45]: zip(*[(1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30)])
Out[45]: [(1, 2, 3), (10, 20, 30)]
```

#### [41]

What's the matter with all these `'\n'` newline charaters? Let's `strip`
them away...

Our problem is that we have a double nesting, say a list of lists
containing the elements that we want to correct...

We have no choice but to unpack the elements with a double loop and
then pack twice our corrected, stripped items again in a list of
lists...

#### [42]

We have a list of lists, whose elements are exactly what we want to
associate to our variable names, this can be done in one sweep using
what is called _sequence unpacking...

The statement 42 represents the compact solution to our problem. By a long time we all knew that 42 is the answer, now eventually we know the question too...

#### [43]

Just to verify that what we have in our variables is the result we are
looking for.

Comment: In  my opinion, the data structure you're trying to impose to your data is inappropriate, how about a dictionary of list of grades, keyed by student names?  `data={t[0].strip():[int(grad.strip()[1:]) for grad in t[1:]] for t in zip(*[open('marks.txt')]*5)}`